# Bokeh Interactively adding lines to figure

Tags: bokeh

I want to plotting lines corresponding to the input user will give through InputText

the code snippet, example.py

```
region = pd.read_csv("region.csv", encoding="utf-8").set_index("plo_region")
TS_LENGTH=360
fig = figure(plot_width=700, plot_height=500, y_axis_type="log",y_range=(10**-2, 10**3))

# callback template
def callback_template(new, table, ts_length):
    # whatever behavior



def callback_region(attr, old, new):
    callback_template(new, region, TS_LENGTH)

    # what to add line in callback function
    curdoc().clear()
    fig.line(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3], legend="sdfds",color="black")
    curdoc().add_root(hplot(inputs, fig))




textInput_region = TextInput(value="", title="region:")
textInput_region.on_change("value", callback_region)


controls = [textInput_region]
inputs = HBox(VBoxForm(controls), width=300)

# put the button and plot in a layout and add to the document
curdoc().add_root(hplot(inputs, fig))
# HOW TO SYNC THE CHANGE ON FIG TO BROWSER ??
```

so if the user gives "Berlin, Hamburg" in TextInput box, it will trigger the callback function and plotting two lines on the figure. Instead, if the user gives "Berlin, Hamburg, Hannover", it will plot three lines.